# Same stored procedure with createSQLQuery and getNamedQuery in Hibernate giving different behaviour

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

I am calling stored procedure named PRC_HB_EMP_SP1 from below code, it is giving expected output.

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
                Query query = session.getNamedQuery("PRC_HB_EMP_SP1");
                query.setParameter("IN_EMPID",empId);
```

but, when I am calling same procedure with below code

```
Query query1 = session.createSQLQuery("CALL PRC_HB_EMP_SP1(?,:IN_EMPID)").addEntity(Employee.class);
                query1.setParameter("IN_EMPID",empId);
```

It is giving me error like

```
 org.hibernate.QueryException: Expected positional parameter count: 1, actual parameters: [] [CALL PRC_HB_EMP_SP1(?,:IN_EMPID)]
```

what can be the reason behind this? I searched on net, i got to know this is issue of paramateres but this sp is having two parameters. first is ouput parameter, second is input parameter

sp

```
create or replace PROCEDURE PRC_HB_EMP_SP1
(
  Out_value OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
  IN_EMPID  NUMBER
)
AS

BEGIN

   open Out_value for
    SELECT EMPID,EMPNAME,ADDRESS,SALARY,EMPAGE
            FROM EMPLOYEE
    WHERE  EMPLOYEE.EMPID = IN_EMPID;

END PRC_HB_EMP_SP1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I gone through same situation.I tried another way...

Instead using out parameter in stored procedure,modify your procedure like below

```
create or replace PROCEDURE PRC_HB_EMP_SP1
(
     IN_EMPID  NUMBER
)
AS

BEGIN

   open Out_value for
    SELECT EMPID,EMPNAME,ADDRESS,SALARY,EMPAGE
            FROM EMPLOYEE
    WHERE  EMPLOYEE.EMPID = IN_EMPID;

select Out_value;
END PRC_HB_EMP_SP1;
```

now ,

```
Query query1 = session.createSQLQuery("CALL PRC_HB_EMP_SP1(:IN_EMPID)").addEntity(Employee.class);
                query1.setParameter("IN_EMPID",empId);
```

and get your out value using,

List res=query1.list();
                System.out.println("result"+res.get(0));

Comment: getting  java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06553: PLS-306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'PRC_HB_EMP_SP1'

Comment: i tried to compile sp but getting this : ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected at select Out_value; Then tried to comment that statement then got this: PLS-00201: identifier 'OUT_VALUE' must be declared

Comment: you have to declare out_value.DECLARE out_value SYS_REFCURSOR;

Comment: declaring SYS_REFCURSOR is again same like 2 parameters to sp